# Nhibernate ArgumentNullException was unhandled Value cannot be null Parameter name: stream

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, nhibernate

I am trying a simple project in NHibernate with MySql but I am getting this exception.
Please Help.
Here is the code

```
class Cat
{


    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string sex { get; set; }
    public decimal weight { get; set; }

}
```

this is my Cat.hbm.xml file

```
<property name="name" type="String">
  <column name="name" length="25" sql-type="varchar" not-null="true"/>
</property>
<property name="sex" column="sex" not-null="true" update="false"/>
<property name="weight" column="weight" not-null="true"/>
```

The app.config file

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="hibernate-configuration" type="NHibernate.Cfg.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NHibernate"/>
  </configSections>

  <hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory>
      <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
      <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
      <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver</property>
      <property name="connection.connection_string">Server=localhost;Database=mohit;User ID=root;Password=root</property>

      <mapping assembly="Cats"/>
    </session-factory>
  </hibernate-configuration>
</configuration>
```

And here is the main program.cs

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)

{
    Configuration cfg = new Configuration();
    cfg.Configure();
    ISessionFactory sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
    ISession session = sessionFactory.OpenSession();

    ITransaction tx1 = session.BeginTransaction();

    Cat c1 = new Cat();
    c1.id = "cat1";
    c1.name = "Fluffy";
    c1.sex = "f";
    c1.weight = new Decimal(3.2);

    var c2 = new Cat();
    c2.id = "cat2";
    c2.name = "Mittens";
    c2.sex = "m";
    c2.weight = new Decimal(4.3);

    session.Save(c1);
    session.Save(c2);
    tx1.Commit();
    Console.WriteLine("successful");

 ITransaction tx2 = session.BeginTransaction();

IList<Cat> cats = session.CreateQuery("FROM cats").List<Cat>();

foreach (Cat c in cats)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c.name);
}

tx2.Commit();
session.Close();
}
```

Please Help I am new to Nhibernate and I am struck on this.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that there is a bug in MySqlConnector...

Add that line in web.config

`<property name="hbm2ddl.keywords">none</property>`

You can find some details solution at the follow links

[Fluent Nhibernate: Can't create database connection to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1298527/fluent-nhibernate-cant-create-database-connection-to-mysql)

[Hibernate Forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=25&t=1001213&view=next)

Comment: Thanks..
There was a problem with mysql connector.
Solved.

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days of digging, finally found a solution.

Set NHibernate property hbm2ddl.keywords to None.
Like below
this._NHConfig.SetProperty("hbm2ddl.keywords", "none");

You can also do it through web.config like above answer.